# Spring Security Shibboleth Open SAML

Tags: maven

Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xx.app:XXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE -> org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.6: Could not transfer artifact org.opensaml:opensaml:pom:2.6.6 from/to Shibboleth (https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -

**Error Screenshot**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Shibboleth</id>
        <name>Shibboleth</name>
        <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ojdbc8.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>





</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo, Dear, code is not uploaded as image, it's only the console error screenshot which is also pasted above as text. Thanks